# How to export multiple databases in Deno?

Tags: database, mongodb, export, deno

I have a code like this:

```
import { MongoClient } from "./deps.ts";

const client = new MongoClient();
await client.connect(Deno.env.get("MONGODB_URI") || "");

const first_db = client.database(Deno.env.get("DB1_NAME") || "");
const second_db = client.database(Deno.env.get("DB2_NAME") || "");

export default  first_db;
export  second_db;


export const firstCollection = first_db.collection("first");
export const secondCollection = second_db.collection("second");
```

This line of the code     `export  second_db;` doesn't work and if I add `const` before `second_db` it gives me another following error:

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'second_db'.deno-ts(2451)
> 'const' declarations must be initialized.deno-ts(1155) Variable
> 'second_db' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I don't know how to export multiple databases?

Also I want to know what is the difference between a database it has `default` type and the other databases they don't have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation for valid [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) syntax.

You can apply it to your situation like this. Let's say your module that includes the exports is called `./module.ts`:

```ts
export const first_db = 'some value';
export const second_db = 'some value';
export default first_db;
```

or

```ts
const first_db = 'some value';
const second_db = 'some value';

export {
  first_db as default,
  first_db,
  second_db,
};
```

Then, you can import them in another module like this:

```ts
import {first_db, second_db} from './module.ts';

// OR

import first_db, {second_db} from './module.ts';

// OR

import {default as first_db, second_db} from './module.ts';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May you say what is the difference between a default and non-default database?

Comment: The `default` keyword is related to the type of export, not the type of database.

Comment: The second solution for export doesn't work and gives this error: `Duplicate identifier 'first_db'.deno-ts(2300)`

Comment: @WDR You’re right: I had a typo there (oops). Fixed now.